# Click, download file and direct to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I'm looking for a javascript that allow me to:

1- Create a link: [a href=...

2- The link direct to a download file: domain.com/download/?id=100

3- Once a user clicked on the link (#1)

4- Download started and direct to another page

Is there anyway I can do this without any plugin, just some javascript and how?

Thank you!

Comment: and http://whathaveyoutreid.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried.

But I will also show you the way.

1. Create a download link `<a href="download file.zip" onclick="redirect">Download</a>`
2. Write a js function:

   `function redirect(){
      setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href="new url";
      }, 3000);
      return true;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

1- http://api.jquery.com/append/
3 - use http://api.jquery.com/append/ again to append an iframe and using PHP set file header to type of downloading file and echo file content...
4. window.location();

Comment: I dont think its really a step when do append you just put the file adress in href of a link no? )